# Identify the Type of Dependency Services for a Windows Service

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I am new to Windows Environment. I am writing a script to restart the Windows Service along with the Dependent Services.

I came across one service **"Wired AutoConfig"** which has some dependent services as below.

```
OS Type : Win Server 2012

Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  RpcSs              Remote Procedure Call (RPC)           
Running  Eaphost            Extensible Authentication Protocol    
Running  Ndisuio            NDIS Usermode I/O Protocol
```

But I dont see *"NDIS Usermode I/O Protocol"* service in the list.

When I put the dependent services in a loop to be restarted one by one, the the script says "It can't find the service".

Is there any command to find out the type of dependent services which is not exactly a Service.

The Command that I am using to find the service and start the service are as below.

```
(Get-Service | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $display_name}|measure).count

Start-Service -Name $Service_Name
```

Please help.

Comment: I have tried to restart the Dependencies and it is working as expected using this command: `Get-Service -DisplayName 'Wired AutoConfig' -RequiredServices | Restart-Service -Force -PassThru`

Comment: Are You sure You want to restart all the services that `Wired AutoConfig` Depends on ? What's the use case of Restarting all the services that Your service depends on ? I understand how You would want ot restart all services that depend on specific service, but not the other way around?